# Laravel not installing after doing everything right

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Laravel not installing when running `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Have tried creating a path for composer on environment variables on my windows OS.

Reinstalling composer.

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.8.17)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.8.17): Loading from cache
Created project in app


  [InvalidArgumentException]                                               
  Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\b  
  in                                                                       
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as describe  
  d in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section              


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist]
[--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL> php artisan
Could not open input file: artisan

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL> composer install
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in
the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Expected everything to work as guided by laravel installation manual and tutorials.
Throws above errors:
[image]

Comment: In a clean directory `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`, dont use `app` use `blog` or `laravel` or anything else. Than you have to `cd blog|laravel|ecc` you can't run `php artisan` from the directory you install you have to enter the installation dir `blog|laravel|ecc`

Comment: Tried this but not working.Stills throws errors.

Comment: $ php artisan
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL\test/vendor/autoload.php): failed
to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL\test\artisa
n on line 18

Answer (score 0):

You should to enter the project's dir and use `composer install`. 
your project created in `app` dir

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you installed composer in you PC? Open `cmd` and run composer if
   return like this type of error ''composer' is not recognized as an
   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' that
   means you need to install composer from this url:
   https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
2. Then, close cmd window and open again and run this command: 
   `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: composer is running just fine. But the rest ,composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog, composer install and php artisan are throwing errors

Comment: @IbrahimClaude run this commands (`composer install`, `php artisan`) in `blog` directory

Comment: @IbrahimClaude problem is you're not moving to new directory which is blog using cd blog

Answer (score 0):

1. Install PHP (check with php -v , it should be or above 7.1)
2. Install composer
3. Installing laravel ' composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ProjectName "5.5.*" ' (remove single quote)
4. composer install (optional)
5. php artisan serve

Comment: Am using php 7.1,have installed composer and is working fine.Running composer install in the directory creates errors. composer install
Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Likewise for php artisan serve

Comment: Have you check composer version " composer --version " in cmd

Comment: I think issued is related with composer. Please follow the step for proper composer installation. http://webdevzoom.com/how-to-install-composer-on-windows/